# Getting some values from this Regexp

Tags: regex, vb.net

```
"_anim\(\d+\)$"
```

Ok, with that, I can check for any string that has the `_anim` suffix alright.
But I need to **get** the value inside the parenthesis (which I expect to be an integer). And I will also need to get the value before the _anim prefix (which I expect to be a string).

That is what I don't get: how do it "get" values, instead of just "knowing" there was a match?

Comment: This is well documented in the MSDN Library.  You are asking too many questions, they are boring and repetitive.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem

Comment: Have I been away that long or why does `\(` and `\)` have to be escaped? But, just a trivial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by putting things into capture groups. in regex these are defined by parentheses, which is why you have to escape them in your regex above, i assume, since you want to check for actual parentheses.

capture groups can be accessed by a number in the order they appear.

```
Dim ResultString As String
Try
    ResultString = Regex.Match(SubjectString, "(.*)_anim\((\d+)\)$").Groups(1).Value
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```

0 would be the entire match, 1 would be the stuff before _anim and 2 would be your digits in this case.